# How to take multiple screenshots in a row in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, screenshot

I needed to take multiple screenshots of various things on a webpage. I went into **Start Menu > Screenshot** and took one.

I noticed that after taking it, it only gives an option to **Save** or **Close** - not to take a new one. Meaning, I then have to go into the menu and type Screenshot again just to take a new one.

Is there a button I can push that takes a new screenshot or is this by design?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Shutter app](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/shutter), installed by

```
apt://shutter
```

from http://shutter-project.org/downloads/ then [tie it to the PrtSc key](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/set-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool/).

Comment: sorry for no reply ^^ forgot to xD Will try it out at some point, though, if I were to accept it, I guess my question becomes off-topic and more suited to software recommendations SE?

Comment: Tying it to the PrtSc key is Linux magic and just may keep it here.